# Exercise advice for newbie

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, muscle

I'm a 22 year old male currently employed as a Program Developer(sedentary work).I weigh 110Kg's and am 186cm's high. I started working out about last week. I normally do 30mins of cardio on bicycle or treadmill, followed by 30mins of weightlifting.

My Questions:
Is it better to focus on one group of muscles each day of weightlifting?

Do you think I should do more cardio than 30mins, if I can hold it?(Time is currently not an issue, but seeing as I just started last week I felt really exhausted after 30mins)

What is a good set of reps and amount of sets for building muscles?

How often should I increase the weight I'm lifting?

What do you think is a reasonable weight I should achieve after 6 months considering I also lowered my caloric intake to the recommended 1.9k and using myfittnespall to help me track everything i eat?

Last of all I have to admit I'm currently hooked on diet coke, and as much as I know it's extremely unhealthy feel I couldn't do this without it. do you think it can also hinder my weight-loss?

3 months and 1 week EDIT:

I don't really know the protocol on this things but i really wanted to thank you all for your answers and comments. 
 As of today I have reached a Body-Weight of 98 KGs and most improtantly my muscle resistance and mass has clearly developed alot lowering my bf percentage to an estimated 20%(tape measurements). 
 Thank you once again for your guidance through this new stage of my life.

PS: I know it doesn't look like it but I'm the OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner in physical fitness, need tips and advices](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/beginner-in-physical-fitness-need-tips-and-advices)

Comment: I would recommend asking for your accounts to be merged. Otherwise, it gets really hard to tell whether a revised question is actually the OP or just someone who signed up with the same name.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Keep us updated with new questions you may have.

Comment: If you are going to do cardio and weightlifting on the same day, then I would recommend to do weightlifting first, as an intense cardio workout totally or almost depletes your glycogen stores. http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/topicoftheweek34.htm

Answer (score 5):

> Is it better to focus on one group of muscles each day of
>   weightlifting?

You will be **very** well served by doing [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) of [Stronglifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/). Ignore everything you've ever been told, and follow either of those two programs for 6-9 months like a religion.

> Do you think I should do more cardio than 30mins, if I can hold
>   it?(Time is currently not an issue, but seeing as I just started last
>   week I felt really exhausted after 30mins)

If you can do it, do it. Personally I like to run for ~30 minutes on my non lifting days primarily because I want to make sure I can always run for a few miles if needed. But remember that your [strength training (done right) will have bigger results than your cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117).

> What is a good set of reps and amount of sets for building muscles?
>   How often should I increase the weight I'm lifting?

Follow the program, they list these out specifically.

> What do you think is a reasonable weight I should achieve after 6
>   months considering I also lowered my caloric intake to the recommended
>   1.9k

You probably have enough fat on you right now that you'll be in the magical place of being able to lose fat and build muscle at the same time. Don't let your training suffer though. If you start missing the reps and weights you're supposed to meet, come back here and ask a question about it, posting as much info as possible so we can help you.

Good programs (like the ones listed above) will maximize your strength gains while keeping you from catching injuries and burning out. Whatever that number is for you, those programs are the roadmap to get there.

> ... using myfittnespall to help me track everything i eat?

Whoever gave you that advice is smart.

> Last of all I have to admit I'm currently hooked on diet coke, and as
>   much as I know it's extremely unhealthy feel I couldn't do this
>   without it. do you think it can also hinder my weight-loss?

[I don't think it's unhealthy; the evidence supporting such claims are barely worthy of even being called "evidence"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19804/taking-protein-powder-with-artificial-sweeteners/19805#19805). If a few diet cokes a day is your biggest health concern, you're fine. Focus on lifting, eating right, and your cardio activity: those constitute 95% of the battle. When you have all that done, if you want to be squeaky clean with no artificial sweeteners, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with just about everything Eric said, especially Starting Strength and Stronglifts 5x5. Another I would consider is the Wendler's 5/3/1 program. Which ever you decide, stick with it for at least 6 months. A year would be better. You will see great results.

I slightly disagree with the cardio. My personal opinion is to do what is commonly referred to as "Finishers". This means sprint workouts that may last as little as 8 to 15 minutes. Jump on a stationary bike and do 30 seconds of sprinting hard, followed by a minute or so of rest. This can be done with running, biking, or even push-ups, other bodyweight excercises, etc. Tabata exercises are great too. Pick a movement (pushups, situps, squats, lunges, kettle bell swings, burpees, etc.), work for 20 seconds and rest for 10 seconds, repeat for 8 sets (4 minutes). If you're feeling froggy, back it up with another one with a different movement, and if you are super motivated try a third movement, but I would rest 1 to 2 minutes between movements.

As for the diet coke, it won't help, but it probably won't hurt too much. Just make sure it doesn't cut into your water intake. Stay hydrated.

Hope that helps. Just getting moving, and making the commitment is the hardest part.